# Processing JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to use a JSON object received from POST inside a php file.
The JSON looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["json"]=>
  string(260) "[{"proddescr":"text1","prodpu":"1","prodcant":"1","prodnume":"text1x"},  {"proddescr":"text2","prodpu":"2","prodcant":"2","prodnume":"text2x"}, {"proddescr":"text3","prodpu":"Price:150.00","prodcant":"quantity:4","prodnume":"text3x"}]"
}
```

I access it like this inside the php file:

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: application.json');
 $x = json_decode($_POST['json']);
 foreach($x as $i => $value){
   print_r($x[$i]);
 }
?>
```

Now... coming from desktop programming... I do not know much about json processing, but I need to be able to access all elements of the JSON array (3 are seen above) and all their contents. I seem to be able to access the main elements using the foreach, but I cannot seem to succeed in accessing the inside elements of each "record"

But the result looks just like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [proddescr] => text1
    [prodpu] => 1
    [prodcant] => 1
    [prodnume] => text1x
)
stdClass Object
(
    [proddescr] => text2
    [prodpu] => 2
    [prodcant] => 2
    [prodnume] => text2x
)
and so on
```

**The purpose is to be able to compose an INSERT statement based on the values from the json array.**

So I need to be able (inside the foreach loop) to get the "proddescr" value, "prodpu" value, "prodcant" value and "prodnume" value from each of those 3 (in this case) array items.

I tried

```
   print_r($x[$i][0]);
```

also

```
   print_r($x[$i]["proddesc"]);
```

in order to be able to access the inside values of the array but does not work (I keep getting "500 Internal server error" when I add the above two print_r.

**How can I access these sub-values of my array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `true` as second parameter in `json_decode` to convert it to array

```
$x = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
foreach($x as $i => $value){
    echo $x[$i]['proddescr'];
    echo $x[$i]['prodpu'];
    echo $x[$i]['prodcant'];
    echo $x[$i]['prodnume'];
}
```

### *Codepad demo*

Comment: You answered first so I accepted your answer. However @DevZer0 had a very nice point in his answer and improved a lot my understanding of PHP. I only marked his answer with "useful" because you answered first, although his answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of issues here, first your using a foreach block but accessing the array as if you were using a for loop. You don't need to set the header here because your not outputting any json.

```
$x = json_decode($_POST['json']);
 foreach($x as $i => $value){
     echo $value->proddescr; //you can access the other objects the same way.
 }
```

You can also access it using the other methods. but based on your iteration setup this method provides the cleanest access.

Comment: Your answer also works. How can I check two good answers here?

Answer (score 0):

I would say 
    $x[$i]->proddescr
etc